# How do I populate a timestamp-typed value in firestore document from javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I'm completely new to firebase and I was wondering how I can add a timestamp to a document on creation. I have an html form and when the user presses submit, the values in the form are supposed to generate a new firestore document within a collection. I want to also have the timestamp of when the document was made inside the document. I'm not sure how to do this.

I've looked into some other similar answers but I'm so new to this, I can't quite understand them? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

```
db.collection("expenses").add({
   expenseName: $('add-expenseName').val(),
   expenseAmount: $('add-expenseAmount').val(),
   expenseLocation: $('add-expenseLocation').val(),
   expenseType: $('add-expenseType').val(),
   expenseDate: //how to I do this? expenseDate should be a timestamp
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a JavaScript Date object, or a Firestore [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) object using the data from your form.  Pass that Date or Timestamp to Firestore in the object that you pass to add().  Unless your form generates either of those two objects, you will have to perform some conversion yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It worked after doing this:

```
var expenseDateVar = new Date();
db.collection("expenses").add({
   expenseName: $('add-expenseName').val(),
   expenseAmount: $('add-expenseAmount').val(),
   expenseLocation: $('add-expenseLocation').val(),
   expenseType: $('add-expenseType').val(),
   expenseDate: expenseDateVar
})
```